# Maven: Dealing with a truly circular dependency

Tags: maven, circular-dependency

I have a somewhat complex situation and I'm not sure what the best way to set up my Maven environment is.

I'm writing a framework to allow the creation of tests for a particular system.  The system can host a variety of applications, and I have a set of tests for each application, which I'd like to keep separate from the framework (which handles the general concept of a "test", and message sending/receiving etc).  Also, the framework provides a generic UI, so it can be built as a war and deployed allowing you to run and configure tests.

What I'm currently doing is building the framework both as a jar and war, listing the framework as a dependency in each application test suite, and pulling in all the framework code using an overlay so each suite can build its own war to deploy.  This is gross.

What I'd like is to be able to specify (probably via profiles) which test suites to build in the framework, and end up with a single framework.war file with the specified suites included.  Trying to build the poms for this I keep running into a circular dependency because:

- To build the tests, the test projects must depend on the framework
- To pull in the specified test jars, the framework must depend on those test projects

Things I've tried:

- Make the test suites sub-projects of the framework:

  - This doesn't work as (I think) I can't package the final result as war (only pom packaging for aggregator projects)
- List the test .jars as system dependencies:

  - This works, but it's gross to have to manually specify a path to the jar
- Put the tests as java packages inside the framework and compile only what you want via filters:

  - technically possible, but I would really prefer the logical separation into separate maven projects as each test suite can be configured too, and I'd like to keep all that config out of the framework pom

What would be ideal would be a parent project pom that would:

1. compile the framework with no tests
2. compile the specified test suites
3. rebuild the framework .war, including the specified test suite jars

I'm not sure if this is possible and/or even advisable, but it seems the best solution to me.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions for organizing this project.

Comment: If I understand the problem description correctly, what you might want is to separate the "framework framework" and the "framework UI" into separate modules. Do the tests need to depend on the UI bits?

Comment: Ahh, an interesting idea.  I need to think a bit about if I could make this work, but thanks, I hadn't thought of that.